# error as runaway argument?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am writing a code for flowchart. When I run the code I am getting runaway argument error. the code is as follows:

```
\documentclass[border=50pt]{standalone} 
\usepackage{utf8}{inputence}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows}

\tikzstyle{startstop}=[rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=red!30]
\tikzstyle{process}=[rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=blue!30]
\tikzstyle{decision}=[rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=blue!30]
\tikzstyle{arrow}={thick,->,>=stealth}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=0.6cm]

\node (start) [startstop] {Initilization of model};
\node (pro1) [process, below of=start] {Calculate time of next sample iteration};
\node (pro2) [process, below of=pro1] {Calculate outputs};
\node (pro3) [process, below of=pro2] {Update discreat states};
\node (pro4) [process, below of=pro3] {Update discreat states};

\end{tikzpicture}
```

can someone help me.

Comment: If i fix the second line to `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`, the last `\tikzstyle` line to use `[...]` instead of `{...}` (like the previous ones) and add `\end{document}`, I get no error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
\usepackage{utf8}{inputence}
```

to

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```

Then change

```
\tikzstyle{arrow}={thick,->,>=stealth}
```

to

```
\tikzstyle{arrow}=[thick,->,>=stealth]
```

(Note that `\tikzset{arrow/.style={thick,->,>=stealth}}` is more recommended.) And append `\end{document}` at last, then the example is compilable.

To make the output looks better, you may also change lines like

```
\node (pro2) [process, below of=pro1] {Calculate outputs};
```

to

```
\node (pro2) [process, below=of pro1] {Calculate outputs};
```

with the help of tikz library `positioning`.

---

A full example with all changes applied:

```
\documentclass[border=50pt]{standalone} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows, positioning}

\tikzset{
  common/.style={
    rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black
  },
  startstop/.style={
    common, fill=red!30
  },
  process/.style={
    common, fill=blue!30
  },
  decision/.style={
    common, fill=blue!30
  },
  arrow/.style={
    thick,->,>=stealth
  }
}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=0.6cm]
  \node (start) [startstop] {Initilization of model};
  \node (pro1) [process, below=of start] {Calculate time of next sample iteration};
  \node (pro2) [process, below=of pro1] {Calculate outputs};
  \node (pro3) [process, below=of pro2] {Update discreat states};
  \node (pro4) [process, below=of pro3] {Update discreat states};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

BTW: You can find a full tutorial about how to draw a flow chart in the [PGF manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf), section 5.

Comment: I even used the same name for the `common` style! :-)